# Early Roman and Etruscan civilization in Northern Italy

Tags: italy, history

We are planning a trip this summer going to several locations in Northern Italy. Currently thinking of Siena, Firenze, Bologna and Milano. Are there any sights either in the towns or in any places relatively nearby (we will cross all the way from Slovenia to Switzerland), that are related to early Roman or Etruscan life? We are interested in museums, old towns, ruins and similar.

Comment: Check Wikipedia, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_civilization . You get various links to cities and artefacts (also in Northern Italy). Most places has some ruins and archaeological finds to be listed here (unfortunately often they are out of context, and no explanation (and maybe just few people know it is a Etruscan writing). So I would recommend check online about what there is on major museums on most large cities.

Answer (score -2):

When I travelled from Slovenia to Milano, I made a stop in Triest. It has a beautiful medieval old center directly at the seaside and a amphitheatre.
https://www.discover-trieste.it/

Comment: The mediaeval part is about 2 millennia too late for what the OP asked for; even the amphitheatre dates to the late Roman Republican era which is several centuries after the period in question